# positioning of created element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown and with that an add input box button which on pressed replicates the dropdown.But when it replicates its position gets changed however I want the position also in similar pattern below is the code and I am using a template so dont have much information about CSS

CSS

```
.collapsing .navbar-form .form-group,
.collapse.in .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.form-bordered .form-group {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #eaedf1;
}
.form-bordered .form-group.form-actions {
    background-color: #f9fafc;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.form-horizontal.form-bordered .form-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.form-bordered .form-group {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.form-horizontal.form-bordered .form-group {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="val_skill">ID Proof</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="val_skill" name="ID_Proof[]" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="Pan Card">Pan Card</option>
            <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
            <option value="Voter ID Card">Voter ID Card</option>
            <option value="Driving License">Driving License</option>
            <option value="Defence ID">Defence ID</option>
            <option value="Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)">Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="inputList"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Add Input field" id="addInputs" />
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>$('#addInputs').click(function () {
    var zzz = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-0 control-label" for="val_skill">ID Proof</label><div class="col-md-12"><select id="val_skill" name="ID_Proof[]" class="form-control"><option value="">Please select</option><option value="Pan Card">Pan Card</option><option value="Passport">Passport</option><option value="Voter ID Card">Voter ID Card</option><option value="Driving License">Driving License</option><option value="Defence ID">Defence ID</option><option value="Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)">Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)</option></select></div></div>';
    $('#inputList').append(zzz);
});</script>
```

Below is the image as you can see ID Proof dropdown is not aligned correctly when I click add input button

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I tried but was not able to that is why I posted image :(

Comment: Please include your CSS and use the code snippet tool when creating your question. Thanks.

Comment: Try putting `<div id="inputList"></div>` between the `.form-group` divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much information, what I can suggest is to put your `#inputList` element outside the `.form-group` div.

**Html code should look like this:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="val_skill">ID Proof</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="val_skill" name="ID_Proof[]" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="Pan Card">Pan Card</option>
            <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
            <option value="Voter ID Card">Voter ID Card</option>
            <option value="Driving License">Driving License</option>
            <option value="Defence ID">Defence ID</option>
            <option value="Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)">Employee ID Card(issued by govt.)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="button" value="Add Input field" id="addInputs" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="inputList"></div> <!-- Container for the new appended Form group -->
```

Reason is that you were appending those `form-group` inside the `col-md-3` element with a `form-group` parent.
Since you have styles set for those `form-group`, padding for example, it will likely affect the position of the appended elements.